# Finding a conjugation given a first integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-analysis

In the ODE given by:
$x'=X(x)$ , where $X$ is my vectorial field $\in C^1$ in an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ ,
 If $X$ have $f$ a first integral  and $df(p)\neq0$ then there exists a neighborhood $V_{p}$ of $p$ such that $X\restriction V_{p}$ is differenciably conjugated to a system:

$Y=(Y_{1},Y_{2},...,Y_{n-1},0)$

So far i tried showing such a conjugation, i know that for every $c$ constant of $f$ the surface (here i don`t know how to call it, manifold maybe) $f^{-1}(c)$ is regular, so there is a map with rank $n-1$, this was my first thought, but i can't build such a conjugation

Also i thought of building such a conjugation withthe gradient of $f$, also couldn't succed

Basically what the question states is that if a system have a first integral then it can be reduced by a simpler system.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried a change of coordinates like $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}, f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$?

Comment: @Evgeny i'm actually trying and think It Works, i Will try to formalize It

Comment: Yeah, I've checked it myself too, it works :)

Comment: @Evgeny thanks! i was struggling with this for days, my question is, by $f^{-1}(c)$ being invariant, i can assure that the whole system is described by a subsystem? cause i was thinking that for eaach $c$ there would be a not necessarly equal subsystem

Comment: I would rather say that when you have a first integral, the dynamics evolves not in the whole part of the phase space with full dimension, but in smaller, less-dimensional part of it. It is quite crucial when you lower the dimension from 2 to 1 and from 3 to 2, for example. You can think of different level sets as different subsystems of your system with lesser dimensions.

Comment: @Evgeny thats my tought, but in the question i'm changing the system at a neighborhood of higher dimension, then the First integral wouldn't be Constant or the system replacable for a lower dimension. I don't know If makes Sense what im saying, i can understand It Works, but sumething bugs me

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your question, but I try to interpret it somehow. When you make a change of variables, a new coordinate (let's call it $y = F(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$) won't take a single value in a domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We just transformed the equations, got $n$ equations again, however in new coordinates the last equation is $\dot{y} = 0$. This means that $y(t) \equiv y(0)$ and we have solved one of the system's equations. If we are interested only in this level set, we can plug that value in other equations: $\dot{x}_i = f_i(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, y(0)$ ($i \leq {n-1}$). ...

Comment: ... Thus, we got less ($n-1$ vs $n$) equations to describe what happens on a level set of first integral.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot